# Would this work be considered a publishable cs research?

Tags: publications, computer-science

I was able to create a new version of a known algorithm with a reduced space complexity than the original by using a different data structure from the one used in the original. It's something like what [Fredman & Tarjan 1984](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=715934) did for the Dijkstra algorithm's time complexity by using Fibonacci heaps. The only difference is that these guys created Fibonacci heaps, I did not create the data structure I used in my work.

Would my work be considered by a respectable journal?
If no respectable journal would accept it, should I consider self-publishing it to, say, arxiv? or should I forget the whole "publish as research" thing and just write a blog post about it?

**P.S**: I'm a fresh CS graduate and I'm not affiliated with any post-graduate program, so I don't have an academic advisor to ask that question to.

Comment: I think you should start by asking this on cs.stackexchange.com. Since you don't have an advisor, they're the ones who could give you feedback on the quality and noteworthiness of your work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on cs.SE.

Comment: Do you know if space is an important limiting factor for the typical use case of your algorithm? How about runtime? Is it parallelisable (so suitable to run on GPUs, where a lower memory footprint is great)? I think this are important things regarding applicability.